# Как копировать все имена классов?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Подскажите, как копировать все имена классов HTML страницы в редакторе VSC?
Это необходимо, чтобы  закинуть в CSS файл и приступить к стилизации без написания классов.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант - написать свой плагин для VSC, который бы генерировал файл с кучей названий классов из html документа. Но зачем? Эту кучу еще разгребать, быстрее будет классы вручную писать, да и некоторые, возможно, не пригодятся вовсе.

Answer (score 0):

есть плагин для этого - eCSStractor for VSCode

Comment: И что он делает? Не отвечайте комментарием, вносите правку в ответ, и желательно с коротким примером использования.